# Kibana histogram - drawing multiple series on a single chart

Tags: kibana

I have an index in Elasticsearch which contains an array of simple objects (key-value  please see example below).

The documents have a timestamp.

I can create separate histograms in Kibana for each key-value (i.e one chart for bytes_sent and another for bytes_received).

I am wondering if there is a way to show both series on one histogram chart.

thanks

Yasir

```
"_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "showstatus",
    "_id": "JhyLAGbcRDyXmrIMmP5lLg",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "_datetime" : "2014-03-21 10:10:10",
       "showstatus": [
          {
             "value": 96451,
             "variable_name": "bytes_sent"
          },
          {
             "value": 435322,
             "variable_name": "bytes_received"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using a newer panel called "multifieldhistogram". I could use it in Kibana3 after a Kibana patch got installed recently.

Please see this link which shows the panel. https://code.csdn.net/chenryn/kibana.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by running two queries, one to plot bytes_sent and one to plot bytes_received. Set the histogram to use the common "value" field. It looks like you may also need to split your data up as well so there's unique records that are timestamp,bytes_sent,value and timestamp,bytes_received,value.

-Brent

Comment: thanks Brent, in the end I ended up indexing each element of the array "showstatus" into a separate document which significantly increases the number of documents. But it looks like this is the only way to do this.

Comment: As I told @OmarOthman, this doesn't work. It would yield the average of the variable "values" inside the showstatus array. And the query 'showstatus.variable_name:bytes_sent' would be true for all the documents that contain in their array showstatus the variable_name "bytes_sent" even though they have additional variable_names

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution to this problem. Is similar to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764868/1051765) given by @OmarOthman but without the aforementioned issues, namely:

1. With the information aggregated in an array is impossible, [is a
   feature that the Elastic team has not addressed
   yet](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/draw-series-from-object/82124/2?u=carlosvega).
2. You would need to disaggregate your documents in separate documents, one with each value of the array. You can use parent
   documents features of elastic to gather them.
3. Once you have the documents with this shape:

Disaggregated form:

```
{ "_datetime" : "2014-03-21 10:10:10", "bytes_sent": 12312, "bytes_received" : 123123 }  
{ "_datetime" : "2014-03-21 10:10:11", "bytes_sent": 12310, "bytes_received" : 12313 }
```

instead of:

```
[…]
"_datetime" : "2014-03-21 10:10:10",
"showstatus": [
{
"value": 96451,
"variable_name": "bytes_sent"
},
{
"value": 435322,
"variable_name": "bytes_received"
}
]
}
[…]
```

You can draw multiple series in Timelion like @OmarOthman [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764868/1051765) but you can also add a secondary (and even tertiary) Y axis using the method [yaxis](https://github.com/elastic/timelion/blob/master/FUNCTIONS.md#yaxis) of Timelion, like:

```
.es('avg:bytes_sent').yaxis(1, label='Bytes sent').bars(), .es('avg:bytes_received').yaxis(2, label='Bytes received', positon='right').bars()
```

With the method [bars](https://github.com/elastic/timelion/blob/master/FUNCTIONS.md#bars) you can draw it as a date histogram.

The other approach proposed by @ OmarOthman would only show the average 'value' taking all the "value" data from all the documents of the showstatus array. This is done because the query 'showstatus.variable_name:bytes_sent' is always true because all documents have that "variable name" in their array showstatus. Hence, both series would be the same unless some documents have not the bytes_sent variable_name inside the array showstatus. Try to draw it, it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score -2):

For sharing the knowledge regarding newer Kibana versions, this is easy using Kibana's TimeLion tool. Select "Timeseries" when you are asked for the Visualization to create.

[image: New Visualization]

It was enough for me to follow the few dialogs that pop up at the beginning to understand how to get started. Something like this should kick it off:

```
.es('showstatus.variable_name:bytes_sent'), .es('showstatus.variable_name:bytes_received')
```

Comment: That would only show the average 'value' taking all the "value" data from all the documents of the showstatus array. This is done because the query 'showstatus.variable_name:bytes_sent' is always true because all documents have that "variable name" in their array showstatus. Hence, both series would be the same unless some documents have not the bytes_sent variable_name inside the array showstatus. Try to draw it, it doesn't work as expected.