# Kibana visualization options for metrics?

Tags: charts, elasticsearch, logstash, metrics, kibana

Advice on the available options for getting all metrics in one chart would be very much appreciated.

Scenario:
I am trying to visualize a set of metrics (cpu, memory, etc..) over time in kibana. I have been able to parse the data so that there are individual fields to represent these metrics:

{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.03.23",
  "_type": "PerfMon",
  "_id": "2UYbSIiKSTiaBsIxLrTNpw",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2015-03-23T17:45:47.511Z",
    "message": "Current performance info:",
    "@version": "1",
    "tags": [
      "multiline"
    ],
    "type": "PerfMon",
    "OverallCPU": "6.471649809040164%",
    "OverallMemory": "53.362655320952484%",
    "ProcessMemory": "1.3G",
    "ProcessVirtualMemory": "3.7G",
    "ProcessCpuUsage": "0.8582689631610962%",
    "TotalDiskSpace": " 55G",
    "FreeDiskSpace": " 40G\n"
  }
}

After converting OverallCPU to integer I was able to add a histogram panel with its "Chart value" set to "max" and "Value Field" set to OverallCPU. This shows me what I want - great! But now I want to add the other metrics to the same panel which is what I'm having trouble doing.

After doing some searches I thought that the structure of the [index shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544330/kibana-histogram-drawing-multiple-series-on-a-single-chart) looked like a step in the right direction since I didn't see any other way to accomplish the type of visualization I want except through queries. But I have been unsuccessful in getting my data into an array.

If getting my data parsed into an array is the only way to get all metrics in one chart then I should probably create a separate question with an appropriate title(agree?).

Since I am new to ELS I didn't want to assume this was the only way to get all metrics into a single chart.

Comment: Sorry. For some reason it didn't send an email when you posted your question. I will do a better job at checking for updates more frequently. To answer your question I am using version 3.0.1 of kibana with 1.1.1 elasticsearch and 1.4.2 logstash. However, I am not running this in production yet so I'm not tied to any specific versions.
Thank you,
Gregg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kibana3, you can define multiple queries and select those for your chart.

Kibana4 is better in that you select multiple metrics for each panel, and have more control over how they are used, aggregated, etc.

Kibana3 is not even available from their website, so I'd suggest jumping into Kibana4.

Comment: Thanks Alain. I'm downloading Kibana 4 now.