# Kibana histogram - Multiple, parameterized lines on a single chart

Tags: kibana

I need to be able to display multiple lines on a single histogram chart, where each line should be represented by a parameter. I have multiple servers for which I want to monitor, say, the CPU usage. My Kibana input data would look something like this:

```
         Timestamp        | Machine |   Name  |  Value |    

2015-06-15T13:31:50.831Z  |   06    | CPUUsage | 26.71 |    
2015-06-15T13:31:50.831Z  |   04    | CPUUsage | 19.95 |    
2015-06-15T13:31:50.831Z  |   03    | CPUUsage | 17.54 |        
2015-06-15T13:31:50.831Z  |   02    | CPUUsage | 20.08 |
```

... and so on.

As you will understand, I need to graph each machine as a single line of a common histogram chart.
At the moment, I have as many Kibana queries as my number of machines I want to monitor, so for the example input above, i'll have 4 queries :

```
Name:"CPUUsage" AND Machine:"02"
Name:"CPUUsage" AND Machine:"03"
Name:"CPUUsage" AND Machine:"04"
Name:"CPUUsage" AND Machine:"06"
```

So it renders like the following :

[image: Kibana CPU Usage monitoring]

Now rendering is great, but my problem is that I have to add a query for each machine I want to monitor, and that is both very cumbersome and not scalable at all, particularly because the number of machines to monitor is constantly evolving.

Finally, what I would like to achieve is to only declare a single query that would like this :

```
Name:"CPUUsage"
```

This query would be machine-agnostic, but for that I need to be able to tell Kibana to split my query in **N** lines using my parameter "**Machine**"... is that even possible ?

Note : I'm currently using Kibana 3.1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Kibana 3 you can refer to the answer by Sushil Verma in the following question: [Kibana histogram - drawing multiple series on a single chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544330/kibana-histogram-drawing-multiple-series-on-a-single-chart/29951810#29951810)

With Kibana 4 onwards, you can create a line chart in Kibana for your purpose.
The x-axis would be date histogram
The Y-axis would be either sum of or max value of "Value"
You can filter your chart by "Name":"CPUUSAGE"
and in the split chart option, you can split lines using the term "Machine"

If it's not a big  hassle to move to the new Kibana, I would suggest doing that